# With Microsoft Edge, how to copy bullet list from one WebPage to another ? why does Paste of Bullet List contain invalid HTML?

Tags: copy-paste, microsoft-edge, text-formatting, bullets, problem-step-recorder

I need help to copy selected text (from from Microsoft Community Website) which is a bullet list to another for posting;
With Edge, copying bullets incurs invalid HTML information
[Edge App - copy bullet list contains invalid HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZjNz.png)
As-Is, problems are

1. pasted bullet list has a line feed after each bullet.
2. invalid HTML reported when pasted content is posted:
   [Steps Recorder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3E5C.gif)
   My manual workaroud involved following additional five steps:
3. Open Word
4. Create Blank Document
5. Paste
6. Copy Pasted Content
7. Paste to Web

Comment: Chrome browser is the answer but unfortunately, it is not my preferred browser.

Comment: Any modern browser, really. Edge is... yeah. I wouldn't ever recommend using it.